# how to set header for change place of app window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i made a wpf app and set the WindowStyle to None
but
when i cant change the place of app 
and
is there any other way to change the size of app without set ResizeMode to CanResizeWithGrip?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="358.685" Width="542.37"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="White">



</Window>
```

Comment: Refer This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23138/WPF-Window-Resizing)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to re size your main window in code.

You can do this anywhere in code by using the following:

```
App.Current.MainWindow.Width = 500;
App.Current.MainWindow.Height = 500;
```

where of course you can substitute 500 with whatever size you want.